# Processing additional CMake files with CMake

Tags: svn, version-control, build, cmake, tweak

I have CMakeLists.txt file, which is under source control. However, to cross-compile I need to do a lot of tweaks, so that all the options like `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=armhf` etc. do not fit the command line limit. To workaround, I just added all the options to the CMakeLists.txt file in the root directory. They look like

```
if(TWEAK_PROJECT_XXX)
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR armhf CACHE STRING "")
...
endif()
```

Of course I cannot commit these tweaks to the source control. However, command line SVN does not let to exclude some files when making a patch like:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd=diff -x -U999999 > full.diff
```

And I need full diff, so I can't use TortoiseSVN GUI for making it (no such possibility in GUI, AFAIK). So I have to manually modify the diff each time to exclude the tweaks of CMakeLists.txt . This is inconvenient.

As a solution I am thinking of moving the tweaks to a separate file, not under source control (and ignore it in SVN) and pass some command-line option to CMake to process that file first of all. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Use a cache file and load it via ` cmake -C <cachefile>`. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake.1.html

Comment: @usr1234567, I think you can post this as an answer, just noting a tricky thing: cmake `-C` option should be followed with the cache file name without a space, like `-CTweaks.txt` .

Comment: According to the documentation, the space could be inserted. If you can reproduce this with a minimal example with the latest CMake, please file a bug.

Comment: I'm using version 3.5.2 . I can't use the latest because it has some bugs which block my build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake offers to load a file with variables and their values to use it as the basis of its cache.
Use such a cache file and load it via

```
cmake -C <cachefile>
```

Documentation: cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake.1.html

Similar, you could use [`load_cache`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/load_cache.html) but it would not fit the needs in your specific case.